# Enlarge width of flex div with column wrap to fit content

Tags: html, css

I would like to have an element that grow and reduce to the dimension of its content only with css rules.

Here an example:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 238px;
}

ul li {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

/* HTML */
<ul>
   <li>item</li> // repeated n times
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/mt_dt/pen/GRJYaNj?editors=1100

 
It should be something like that:
    https://ibb.co/6wmYkGX

Comment: You want the columns equal width as the container but you also want to limit the height?

Comment: your pen an image are the same, plz explain more

Comment: Sorry I hardcoded the width of the UL to make the picture, it should be 0 (inline) and take the width of it's children wrapped. I fixed the pen. No width declared in the UL css rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have each element on the list to be as wider as the ul element, you need to remove hardcoded height and flex properties (they have no use) from the ul element and set width: 100%; on the lis:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 235px;
}

ul li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Have a look [to this codepen](https://codepen.io/avcajaraville/pen/oNXaRqj). Hope it helps!

Comment: The contrary.
I want the UL to be as wider as the wrapped column put together as pic related, therefore with two column the UL should be as large as the width of two column.
https://ibb.co/6wmYkGX